# Create multiple partitions within an EBS via HashiCorp Packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer, chroot

I am trying get an Amazon AMI and add multiple partitions to the EBS volume then generate a new AMI, where I should be able to spin up new EC2 instances using this newly generated AMI. I am attempting this via HashiCorps Packer Tool.

This is the output I expect:

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda                      202:0    0   200G  0 disk
├─xvda1                   202:1    0    30G  0 part /
├─xvda2                   202:2    0 165.0G  0 part
│ └─appsvg-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0    15G  0 lvm  
│ └─appsvg-lv_u001 (dm-1) 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /u001
│ └─appsvg-lv_u002 (dm-2) 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /u002
│ └─appsvg-lv_u002 (dm-3) 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /u003
└─xvda3                   202:3    0   5.0G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Do I need to use chroot_mount or ami_block_device_mappings (array of block device mappings) or launch_block_device_mappings...

Little confused with this... Any support would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [UserData](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#user_data) or use a packer [shell provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html) to configure LVM

Comment: This approach is to configure the LVM after the EC2 instance is started? However the root ebs volume can not be partitioned...? it must be assigned as a secondary volume to partition?

Comment: Yes, use ami_block_device_mappings to add secondary EBS volumes, there is no direct solution to use LVM on the root volume.

Comment: Im in search of a method which is to partition the volumes and mount to /path1, /path2 etc as part of the build process. Not after the instance/ebs is started.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same need, and I was able to accomplish it by using the amazon-import post-processor.

Because I needed an installation that had fewer packages than the default minimal installation, plus build an image that included different partitions for /var, /var/log, /var/log/audit, and apply flags like noexec and nosuid to them I found it much easier to find a method that allowed me to use a kickstart file because it supports all these options at install time.

This allowed me to build an image like normal using vsphere or virtualbox, and still have the final output artifact as an AMI.  The following packer template will accomplish this on vsphere.  You'll note that there is no partition information or package installation other than cloud-init in this template because it's all in the centos7.cfg kickstart file I wrote for this template.

One important thing is to name your ami so it has 'centos' in the name and create a user account in your kickstart file called 'centos'.  This is because EC2 will try to copy the ssh keys you select when you launch an instance to the default user account for your operating system type, which is determined by string matching the ami name and happens to default to centos for CentOS operating system images.

```
{
"builders": [{
    "type": "vmware-iso",
    "name": "centos7",
    "guest_os_type": "centos-64",
    "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
    "iso_checksum": "5848f2fd31c7acf3811ad88eaca6f4aa",
    "iso_url": "http://some-server.com/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso",
    "ssh_username": "root",
    "ssh_password": "password",
    "floppy_files": [
        "centos7.cfg"
    ],
    "boot_command": [
        "<wait><esc><esc>",
        "linux inst.ks=hd:fd0:/centos7.cfg net.ifnames=0<enter>"
    ],
    "boot_wait": "5s",
    "disk_size": 100000,
    "vmx_data": {
        "cpuid.coresPerSocket": "1",
        "ethernet0.present": "true",
        "ethernet0.virtualDev": "vmxnet3",
        "ethernet0.startConnected": "true",
        "ethernet0.addressType": "generated",
        "ethernet0.networkName": "VMWARE VLAN",
        "virtualhw.version" : "7",
        "config.version": "8",
        "scsi0.virtualDev": "lsilogic",
        "scsi0.present": "TRUE",
        "ide1.0.present": "FALSE",
        "memsize": "32768",
        "numvcpus": "4",
        "smc.present": "TRUE",
        "hpet0.present": "TRUE",
        "ich7m.present": "TRUE"
    },
    "remote_type": "esx5",
    "remote_port": "22",
    "remote_host": your.esxi.host.com",
    "remote_username": "esxi_username",
    "remote_password": "esxi_password",
    "remote_datastore": "abcd-efgh-d1234k-sdfkl34",
    "headless": false,
    "ssh_wait_timeout": "600s",
    "ssh_pty": true,
    "shutdown_timeout": "60s",
    "format": "ova"
}],
"provisioners": [
    {
     "type": "shell",
     "execute_command": "{{ .Vars }} sudo -E bash {{ .Path }}",
     "inline": "yum -y install cloud-init",
    }
],
"post-processors" : [
 [
 {
  "type": "amazon-import",
  "access_key": "...",
  "secret_key": "...",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "s3_bucket_name": "mys3bucketname",
  "license_type": "BYOL",
  "ami_name": "something-with-centos-in-it"
 }
 ]
]
}
```

Comment: HI Nathan, would you happen to have the full packer template to see your approach to this?

Comment: I've updated my original answer to include the full template.

Comment: I had the equivalent setup with a preseed/ubuntu build on an x86 macbookpro and it worked great through vmimport. Now I upgraded to ARM and there is no virtualbox-iso that would work, I cannot repeat the exercise, so I'm looking for a way of either repartitioning an installed AMI or generating another AMI using the data from one installed in the equivalent place on the install image as it is built. As virtualbox-iso is not an option now, I'm thinking an AWS packer builder, but which is best for this?